# Rolling queue size

Tags: r, data.table

I want to calculate number of items waiting or queued over. Let's say, I have fixed capacity of 102 item/hour and different incoming items for 9 hours.

as data table:

```
dt<-data.table(hour = c(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9),
               incoming = c(78,102,115,117,105,99,91,80,71),
               capacity = rep(102,9))
```

I want to calculate queued items in each period.
In 1 and 2 capacity is enough and queue is 0.
In 3, 13 items are queued
In 4, 15+13 backlogged items are queued.
In 6, there were 31 backlogged items and 3 items are deducted so 28 were queued.

I have tried several options but could not figure out how to calculate.

Result should be:

[image]

Comment: I think this is a fun problem to solve in R, but practically speaking - just Rcpp it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Explicit looping in R won't get you far, and I don't see a vectorized solution for this, but this is trivial to solve using `Rcpp`:

```
library(Rcpp)

cppFunction("NumericVector queue(NumericVector x) {
  NumericVector res(x.size());
  res[0] = std::max<double>(0, x[0]);
  for (int i = 1, size = x.size(); i < size; ++i) {
    res[i] = std::max<double>(0, res[i-1] + x[i]);
  }
  return res;
}")

dt[, queued := queue(incoming - capacity)][]
#   hour incoming capacity queued
#1:    1       78      102      0
#2:    2      102      102      0
#3:    3      115      102     13
#4:    4      117      102     28
#5:    5      105      102     31
#6:    6       99      102     28
#7:    7       91      102     17
#8:    8       80      102      0
#9:    9       71      102      0
```

Answer (score 0):

Another alternative:

```
require(data.table)

dt<-data.table(hour = c(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9),
               incoming = c(78,102,115,117,105,99,91,80,71),
               capacity = rep(102,9))   


dt$incoming_capactity<- dt$incoming-dt$capacity

dt$carriedover<- 0
dt$carriedover[1]<-  max(0,dt$incoming_capactity[1]) #added

for( i in 2:length(dt$carriedover)) {
  dt$carriedover[i]<- max(0,dt$incoming_capactity[i] + dt$carriedover[i-1])
}

dt
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd create a separate function to get queued number like @sebastian-c did, but with @R.S. 's logic. Like this

```
get_queue <- function(x){
    n <- length(x)
    y <- c(max(0, x[[1]]), rep(0, n - 1))
    for(i in 2:n){
        y[i] <- max(0, y[i - 1] + x[i])
    }
    y
}
```

And then

```
dt[,incoming_capacity := incoming - capacity]
dt[,queued := get_queue(incoming_capacity)]
```